# uses for namespaces in sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm reading though this db query, and i'm not sure that I need the `l.` before each selection..

What does `l.` as in `l.id` or `l.node_id` stand for? Do I need it? If not, what would I use it for?

```
        SELECT
            l.id, l.node_id,
            l.name, l.phone, l.email
        FROM
            leads l
        WHERE
            l.active = 1
            AND agent_id = '.$user->id.'
        GROUP BY l.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an alias, standing for the table. `FROM leads l` means "from the table `leads`, which will be referred to as `l` elsewhere in this query". To write the query without an alias, you could write:

```
SELECT leads.id, leads.node_id,
       leads.name, leads.phone, leads.email
  FROM leads
 WHERE leads.active = 1
   AND agent_id = ...
 GROUP BY leads.id
;
```

But since there's only one table in this query, you don't need to use any prefix at all; something like this is perfectly fine:

```
SELECT id, node_id,
       name, phone, email
  FROM leads
 WHERE active = 1
   AND agent_id = ...
 GROUP BY id
;
```

Normally a prefix like this (either `leads.` or `l.`) is used when there's some ambiguity that the query-writer wants to address — either to avoid confusing the database engine, or to avoid confusing a human reading the query, or both — but some people are in the habit of always using these prefixes, both for explicitness and so they never risk introducing an ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

`l` is an alias for the `leads` table. You don't really need aliases when you only query one table. But if you were querying two tables that both have a column called `id` you would have to type out the full table name `<table_name>.id` to distinguish between the two id columns, aliases make this shorter.

example:

```
SELECT
    l.id, r.id, l.node_id,
    l.name, l.phone, l.email
FROM
    leads l, another_table r
WHERE
    l.active = 1 
    AND agent_id = '.$user->id.'
    AND r.id = l.id
GROUP BY l.id
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The "l" is an alias for your leads table.  Use of an alias is often more convenient than prefixing your column references with the full table name, as it is quicker to type (as you can see it is in this case).  As for why you need to prefix your references at all, with either an alias or the literal name - in the case of a single-table select, it isn't absolutely necessary.  However, if you ever decided that you needed to join to any other table (which you very often do need to do), then you would very likely have to prefix your column references with the name (or alias) of the table they originate in.  This is because there could easily be name conflicts between the tables, and the server would need to know where to go to resolve the reference.